Intel RealSense D415 ROS2 Jazzy Issues
Has anyone been able to get the D415 working with ROS2 Jazzy? The initial wrapper was released a few days ago.
I am trying to first build the realsense2_camera_msgs then the realsense2_camera packages but am getting an issue with empy python module where it is not finding the interpreter attribute.
